Coupling/Ordering of Brownian bridges
Suppose I have two 1D Brownian bridges $(B^{(1)}_t,t\in [0,1]),(B^{(2)}_t,t\in [0,1])$, one from $0$ to $0$ and one from $x$ to $y$ where $x,y \geq 0$. Is there a neat way to show that there exists a coupling so that $\vert B^{(1)}_t \vert \leq \vert B^{(2)}_t \vert$ almost--surely for all $t \in [0,1]$? I have a partial proof but this needs a variety of case distinctions so I wondered if there was a good way to show this.

just to be sure, you mean 2D Browinan bridges both parametrized by $[0,1]$, right?

Pretty sure he means 1D Brownian bridges, but his first coordinate is time.

It seems that the following coupling is a good candidate.
For simplicity I only treat the case $x=y=1$ and denote $W^{(1)} = B^{(1)}$ as well as $W^{(2)} = B^{(2)} - 1$ which are now two BB pinned at $0$ at $t=0$ and $t=1$.
Denote $\tau_- = \inf( t \in [0,1] \mid W^{(1)}_t = -1/2 )$ the first hitting time of $-1/2$ and similarly $\tau_+ = \sup( t \in [0,1] \mid W^{(1)}_t = -1/2 )$ the last hitting time of $-1/2$. Conditionally on the event where the latter two exist and on the random pair $(\tau_-,\tau_+)$ I believe that the process $W^{(1)}_t, t \in [\tau_-,\tau_+]$ is again a BB pinned at $-1/2$. I don't have a nice or clean proof of this right now so I'll ask the OP and other interested readers to confirm I am not blundering here. The intuition is that conditionally on $(\tau_-,\tau_+)$ and on the excursions of the BB outside $[\tau_-,\tau_+]$ in $]-1/2, +\infty [$, the trajectory inside $[\tau_-,\tau_+]$ should be independent and again a BB, by a kind of BB version of the strong Markov property (the proof is clear I believe at least for a random walk on $\mathbb Z$ with conditioned final state).
You can now use the reflection principle with reflection horizontal axis $y = -1/2$ and set $W^{(2)}_ t =  - 1 - W^{(1)}_t$ for $t \in [\tau_-,\tau_+]$ and set $W^{(1)}_t = W^{(2)}_t$ elsewhere. On $ t \in [\tau_-,\tau_+]$ it holds $ | W^{(1)}_t | = | W^{(2)}_t + 1 | $ while elsewhere $  W^{(2)}_t = W^{(1)}_t \geq -1/2 $ so that the distance to $0$ is smaller than the distance to $-1$. In the end, $ | W^{(1)}_t | \leq | W^{(2)}_t + 1 | $ .

Thank you Mathias, this is quite elegant. I agree with you that the conditional on $(\tau_-,\tau_+)$ the process restricted to $t\in [\tau_-,\tau_+]$ is a Brownian bridge.

This approach doesn't work when $y=0$ (equivalently $x=0$) because you're not sufficiently bounded away from $0$. In that case there is a different coupling: Run the two BB independently until $\tau = \inf{t: \vert B^{(1)}t \vert = \vert B^{(2)}t \vert  }$. If $B^{(1)}\tau = B^{(2)}\tau$, then let them run together. If $B^{(1)}\tau = - B^{(2)}\tau$, set $B^{(1)}_t = -B^{(2)}_t$ for all $t \geq \tau$. This coupling has the desired property.

Your coupling then also work to couple a BB from $x$ to $y$ with a BB from $x-y$ to $0$ (without loss of generality $x-y>0$). And in a second step using the coupling I described you can couple it to a BB from $0$ to $0$.
